# S3 Policy not working when resource is specified

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-policy

I have a rails app set up to upload files to S3
I have an IAM user with an inline policy attached to the user.

When I use the following policy everything works just fine:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1494133349000",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Now when I try to specify the ARN of my bucket, I get an access denied error in my app.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1494133349000",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

The ARN is copied directly from my bucket.  No clue why the second policy doesnt work. It should according to everything i've read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your bucket:

```
"Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
]
```

This is your bucket *and* the objects in your bucket:

```
"Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
]
```

Comment: That's it exactly!   For whatever reason I assumed that giving access to the bucket gave access to it's object as well.  Thanks!